# Optimal packing of 128 bit array into a number

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have a hash whose values are set/unset based on some condition(essentially a bitmap). This hash needs to be stored as a string(in a blob) in the most optimal way possible. I figured I could use a bit array and pack them into a number and store this number as a string. Any ideas on how I can go about doing this? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a java.util.BitSet?

Comment: Java's `String` is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. "blob" usually refers to a sequence of bytes/bits with unrestricted content. Please make clear which one you want. If it's actually a blob, you can just store the number verbatim using 16 bytes.

Comment: Which requirements must the string fulfill (forbidden characters)? Is it a byte-string, a unicode string (how is it stored as UTF-8, UTF-16 or else)? And is there a reason you can't use a blob as it is instead of a string?

Comment: You can use a `ByteBuffer`. `BitSet` has a very annoying behaviour when a bit is not set. Also, where do you read from, where do you write to? Why do you want a string representation?

Comment: @delnan, that would be a sequence of bytes. I'd need to store the number I guess

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a `BigInteger`. It has a constructor taking a byte array as an argument, and a `.toByteArray()` to get the number as a byte array:

```
final BigInteger myHash = new BigInteger(theByteArray);
final byte[] theArray = myHash.toByteArray();
```

Comment: By pure habit. I always make variables `final` when they can be.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store it as a string, you should probably do a base 64 encoding of the number. You could use the [Base64 class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from Apache Commons Codec.  E.g.

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(myBinaryData);
```

Comment: According to the last edit, OP actually wants a byte string. Also, since I'm here: Base 64 would be very inefficient as `String` os UTF-16, not ASCII. If I'm not mistaken, overhead would grow from about 33% (when targeting ASCII) to about 166%. You'd need ca. 43 bytes, rather than ca. 22 bytes, for a 128 bit number.

Comment: @delnan I don't think the OP understands what he wants.

Comment: If you need printable ASCII characters and want to squeeze out the last bit there is [ASCII85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85).

Answer (score 0):

I would use two `long` values or four `int` values.  You won't get more efficient than this.  You can use a byte[] if you going to need to convert to/from a byte[] in any case.

Answer (score -2):

A 128-bit array is just an unsigned long.  Very easy and natural packing.

Comment: Uh, no. A long is 8 bytes, not 16.

Comment: Doh.  Sorry, you are correct, of course.  I was having a brain cramp.  Two longs are of course needed.